# java regex, match specific amount of html tag pairs

Tags: java, regex

I am having trouble understanding the following regex result in Java.

Basically I want to identify a string that has 3 span tags with some text content, nothing before or after this.

So this would be valid: `<span>a</span><span>b</span><span>c</span>`, if adding or taking away a span pair then it would become invalid.

I tried simplifying this to just match only one tag pair using the following regex: `^<span>.+?(?=</span>)</span>$`.

This matches `<span>a</span>` as expected, but also matches `<span>a</span></span>` and `<span>a</span><span>b</span>` which I don't understand.

My assumption with the regex parts are:

`^` - match beginning of input

`<span>` - match literal `<span>`

`.+?(?=</span>)` - match one or more characters (minimal amount) until reaching literal `</span>`, which I assume would match just `a`

`</span>` - match the literal `</span>` after the `a`

`$` - match end of input

What am I missing here.  Why is a second literal `</span>` allowed at the end of the input I'd expect to fail.  I sort of expect that it has to do with the `.*?(?=</span>)` not behaving as I expect and matching the final `</span>` whereas I thought it would only match up to the next occurrence of `</span>`

Comment: How about this regex? `^(<span>.+?</span>){3}$`

Comment: That is still matching 4 sets of spans as well. but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you're right. I guess you need a negative lookahead to match everything but `</span>` elements: `^(<span>((?!</span>).)+?</span>){3}$`

Comment: ah yes, this seems to do the trick.  Thank You!